# how to configure loadbalancer in fuse cluster?

Tags: jbossfuse

I had setup cluster in Jboss fuse 6.3.0 for server01 and server02 node. Can anyone suggest me that how to configure loadbalancer in fuse cluster?

Till now i have done following things to achieve clustering on Jboss Fuse.

1.I had setup 2 Fuse on 2 different servers, and then join them together to form a fabric cluster.
2.I changed in file "org.apache.karaf.management.cfg" under etc/ and change the RMI related port.

```
  rmiRegistryPort=1199
  rmiServerport=445
```

Also there are a few more port you need to adjust,org.apache.karaf.shell.cfg, change the:

```
sshPort
```

and last inside system.properties

```
org.osgi.service.http.port
activemq.port
activemq.jmx.url
```

3. Then getting back to setting the cluster of fabric, start up JBoss Fuse by going into bin/ and execute fuse on server one. After it starts up, create a fabric by entering the following command:

   fabric:create --wait-for-provisioning

4.This spins up a fabric on a container call root, now, start up JBoss Fuse on server2 by going to bin/ and execute fuse on server two. And instead of creating a fabric, we are going to join, by entering following command, as fabric:join [options] zookeeperUrl [containerName].

```
fabric:join --zookeeper-password admin 192.168.0.1:2181 root1
```

5. Then go to your fuse command line console in Server1 and type:

   config:edit io.fabric8.zookeeper
   config:proplist

This will give you your zookeeper details:

```
    JBossFuse:karaf@root> config:proplist
    service.pid = io.fabric8.zookeeper
    zookeeper.password = ZKENC=YWRtaW4=
    zookeeper.url = 192.168.0.1:2181
    fabric.zookeeper.pid = io.fabric8.zookeeper
```

6.And now Ihave successfully created a fabric on 2 servers
  - If you type in container-list in the command line, you should be able to see we now have 2 working server

```
 JBossFuse:karaf@root> container-list 
[id]                           [version] [connected] [profiles]                                         [provision status]
root*                          1.0       true        fabric, fabric-ensemble-0000-1, jboss-fuse-full    success
root1                          1.0       true        fabric
```

7.And Now if you login to Fuse management console, under Runtime-> Containers you will see the 2 root containers on both servers
  -root
  -root1

But now my question is that how to achieve load balancer in server1 and server2. I have created my fabric profile and it shared with 2 nodes and then deployed CXF-RS webservice on my fabric profile but request is not going to server2.

Can anyone suggest me that where i need to configure load balancer configuration for Fuse server1 and server2?

Thanks,
Prakash

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use HTTP Gateway for loadbalancing HTTP endpoints in JBoss Fuse Fabric mode.

For more info, see:
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_fuse/6.3/html/fabric_guide/gateway

Comment: Thank you Tadayoshi Sato! It make sense.

Comment: Hi @Tadayoshi Sato , Using HTTp Gateway , loadbancer is working on fuse fabric container and their LB port is 9000 and rest(cxf-rs) services are access through this LB port(9000) on my local machine but it is not accessing through out side the machine(over LAN) . I added the following port in firewall rule engine(in bound and out bound) but still services are not accessible on other machine . ports: 9000, 8181,8182,8183,8184. LB Service URL is http://localhost:9000/cxf/status/status/custId/123

Comment: Have the remote machines joined the Fabric ensemble?

Comment: Yes, i did that using below command.  \n                                                      
JBossFuse:karaf@root2> fabric:join 192.168.10.1:2181
Ensemble password: ZooPass1
============================
JBossFuse:karaf@root3> fabric:join 192.168.10.1:2181
Ensemble password: ZooPass1
                                                                    
JBossFuse:karaf@root> fabric:ensemble-add root2 root3
This will change of the zookeeper connection string.
Are you sure want to proceed(yes/no):yes
JBossFuse:karaf@root> fabric:ensemble-list
[id]
root
root2
root3